# AES 256 32 bytes key Encrypt/Decrypt Java

Tags: java, xml, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to Encrypt XML message (it comes as String) using AES 256 with 32 bytes key. I have tried the following (from http://aesencryption.net/) :

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
/**
Aes encryption
*/
public class AES
{

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey ;
    private static byte[] key ;

    private static String decryptedString;
    private static String encryptedString;

    public static void setKey(String myKey){


        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            System.out.println(key.length);
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
            System.out.println(key.length);
            System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    public static String getDecryptedString() {
        return decryptedString;
    }
    public static void setDecryptedString(String decryptedString) {
        AES.decryptedString = decryptedString;
    }
    public static String getEncryptedString() {
        return encryptedString;
    }
    public static void setEncryptedString(String encryptedString) {
        AES.encryptedString = encryptedString;
    }
    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);


            setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
                final String strToEncrypt = "My text to encrypt";
                final String strPssword = "C0BAE23DF8B51807B3E17D21925FADF273A70181E1D81B8EDE6C76A5C1F1716E";
                AES.setKey(strPssword);

                AES.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());

                System.out.println("String to Encrypt: " + strToEncrypt); 
                System.out.println("Encrypted: " + AES.getEncryptedString());

                final String strToDecrypt =  AES.getEncryptedString();
                AES.decrypt(strToDecrypt.trim());

                System.out.println("String To Decrypt : " + strToDecrypt);
                System.out.println("Decrypted : " + AES.getDecryptedString());

    }

    }
```

I tried to change key array lenght from 16 to 32 and used a larger input String
(I think that's 32 lenght key) but that doesn't work.

> ```
> key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 32);
> ```

Message to encrypt will be as simple as:

```
<Estructure>
   <General>GENERAL DATA</General>
</Estructure>
<Datos>
   <DATE>20140606</DATE>
</Datos>
```

When I run that I get the following Exception:

> Error while encrypting: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters

It works perfectly when using 16 byte Lenght key. How can I make it work with 32 bytes?

Comment: is there a question here? "It doesn't work" is not acceptable.

Comment: What is exception you got and at what place?

Comment: Post Edited. I get an Exception when trying to use 256 bits key (32 Bytes). But same code works perfectly when using 128 Bits (16 Bytes). How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default anything above 128 bit encryption is disabled in the JVM, because Oracle is operating under US jurisdiction.

If you want more than 128 bit encryption you have to download [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html) and put the jar files in your JRE/JDK

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I'm going to try that!

Comment: That solved it for me. But I had to download [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7] From:   [1]: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html